# Will the Average Kinetic Energy of ejected Electrons in Photo electric effect change with Intensity of Radiation?

Tags: optics, photons, photoelectric-effect

Please realize, that I am not talking about the Maximum Kinetic energy of Photoelectrons. I understand that the Max K.E. depends upon the energy of radiation used.

But the Kinetic enrgy of most electrons is less than Max K.E. so will the average K.E. of all electrons also be unaffected on increasing Intensity of Light, or as the no. of ejected electrons increase then their average K.E. will also increase?
Or is this indeterminable?

Answer (score 0):

there will just be more electrons , but with the same average K.E.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion, I think that if we believe the electrons to be gaseous molecules, their individual average Kinetic Energy will depend only on the the absolute temperature of the photoelectric tube (because KE=3/2kT).

Now, as the intensity increases, the number of photoelectrons increases and thus their energy distribution. So, the extra energy is distributed among the newly generated(excited) photoelectrons from the metal body. But as a whole, the average kinetic energy remains the same.

Note: These are my reasonings, I don't know if there are groundbreaking researches
done in this area.